# Detecting the pattern of a binary sequence and extend the sequence with same pattern in R

Tags: r, date, time-series

I am looking for a solution to effective capture the pattern of a sequence with value just 0 and 1. The data looks like:

```
   id            date       occurrence
   <chr>       <date>        <dbl>
 1 10010020    2019-08-01        0
 2 10010020    2019-08-02        0
 3 10010020    2019-08-03        1
 4 10010020    2019-08-04        0
 5 10010020    2019-08-05        0
 6 10010020    2019-08-06        1
 7 10010020    2019-08-07        0
 8 10010020    2019-08-08        0
 9 10010020    2019-08-09        1
10 10010020    2019-08-10        0
```

and I would like to extend the data frame to something like:

```
   <chr>       <date>        <dbl>
 1 10010020    2019-08-01        0
 2 10010020    2019-08-02        0
 3 10010020    2019-08-03        1
 4 10010020    2019-08-04        0
 5 10010020    2019-08-05        0
 6 10010020    2019-08-06        1
 7 10010020    2019-08-07        0
 8 10010020    2019-08-08        0
 9 10010020    2019-08-09        1
10 10010020    2019-08-10        0
11 10010020    2019-08-11        0
12 10010020    2019-08-12        1
13 10010020    2019-08-13        0
14 10010020    2019-08-14        0
15 10010020    2019-08-15        1
16 10010020    2019-08-16        0
17 10010020    2019-08-17        0
18 10010020    2019-08-18        1
19 10010020    2019-08-19        0
20 10010020    2019-08-20        0
21 10010020    2019-08-21        1
22 10010020    2019-08-22        0
23 10010020    2019-08-23        0
24 10010020    2019-08-24        1
25 10010020    2019-08-25        0
26 10010020    2019-08-26        0
27 10010020    2019-08-27        1
28 10010020    2019-08-28        0
29 10010020    2019-08-29        0
30 10010020    2019-08-30        1
```

I know the title may be the reason why I have not found the answer yet, so any suggestions on a good problem description will be welcomed.

Cheers

Comment: You could do `df$occurrence <- rep(c(0, 0, 1), length.out = nrow(df))`

Comment: You need to better define what you consider a "pattern". Am I correct in assuming you want to split a sequence in its smallest possible identical subsequences for detecting a "pattern"?

Comment: Hi, here the 0,0,1 sequence is just an example, in reality this is unknown. @AndrewGustar

Comment: @Roland,  yes! For a sequence "0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, " I would like to predict the next value by capturing "0, 0, 1, 0, 1" as a recurring subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will find the shortest repeated sequence in a vector of 0s and 1s...

```
find_rep <- function(x) {
   head(x, which(sapply(1:(length(x) - 1), 
                        function(z) sum(abs(x[-(1:z)] - head(x, -z)))
                        ) == 0)[1])
}

find_rep(c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0))
[1] 0 0 1 1 0

find_rep(c(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1))
[1] 0 1 0
```

It compares `x` against shifted versions of itself, and returns the shortest section for which the difference is zero.

You can then repeat the sequence with something like `rep(y, length.out = n)` where `y` is `find_rep(x)` and `n` is the number of rows in your data.